# Data not being able to be moved in PHP

Tags: php, html, mysql

I hope you are doing great. Ok, I had this script that used to work. When I added the file input. It started not to work. I checked my lines and all. it should make since but I don't know why it's not working. I hope you can help me with this. Thanks in advance :D

Useful pieces of my code:

My executing code:

```
<?php
    include 'Header.php';
    include 'debugging.php';
    ?>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
<style>
    form {
        background-color: #FFFFC2;
    }
    .div_1 
    {
        height: 87vh;
    }
</style>

        <br>
        <br>
        <div class="div_1">
        <div id="div_2">
        <br>
        <h1>User Registration</h1>
        <!--this is an HTML form to allow the user to input data and submit the webpage by clicking the button-->  
        <form action="Sign_Up.php" method="post">
            <fieldset>
                <p><b>Enter Username</b>
                    <input type="text" name="UserName" size="20" value="" />
                <p><b>Enter First Name</b>
                    <input type="text" name="FName" size="20" value="" />
                <p><b>Enter Last Name (Optional)</b>
                    <input type="text" name="LName" size="20" value="" />
                <p><b>Enter Email</b>
                    <input type="email" name="Email" size="50" value="" />
                <p><b>Enter Password</b>
                    <input type="password" name="Password" size="10" value="" />
                <p><b>Select Profile Picture</b>
                    <input type="file" name="Image" size='70' value="" />
                <p><b>Enter Date of Birth (Optional)</b>
                    <input type="date" name="DOB" size="10" value="" />
                <div align="center">
                    <input type ="submit" value ="Register" />
                </div>  
                <input type="hidden" name="submitted" value="1" />
            </fieldset>
        </form>   
        </div>
        </div>
        <?php
//this section of code is PHP to validate the contents of the form controls and populate an array 
//with error messages
        if (isset($_POST['submitted'])) {
//declare variables to store the uploaded data
            $username = '';
            $dob = '';
            $fn = '';
            $ln = '';
            $Email = '';
            $Password = '';

            $errors = array();

            if (empty($_POST['UserName']))
                $errors[] = 'You must enter a username';
            else 
                $username = trim($_POST['UserName']);

            if (empty($_POST['FName']))
                $errors[] = 'You must enter a first name';
            else 
                $fn = trim($_POST['FName']);

            if (empty($_POST['Email'])) {
                $errors[] = 'You must enter an email';
            } elseif (!filter_var($_POST['Email'], FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
                $emailErr = "Invalid email format";
            } else
                $Email = trim($_POST['Email']);

            if (empty($_POST['Password']))
                $errors[] = 'You must enter a Password';
            else
                $Email = trim($_POST['Password']);

            $ln = trim($_POST['LName']);
            $dob = trim($_POST['DOB']);

            if (empty($errors)) {
//no errors so try and connect to the DB  

         include 'User.php';

        $user= new DO_User();


        $user->firstName = trim($_POST['FName']);
        $user->lastName = trim( $_POST['LName']);
        $user->userName = trim( $_POST['UserName']);
        $user->email = trim($_POST['Email']);
        $user->password = trim($_POST['Password']);
        $user->dob = trim( $_POST['DOB']);

        if( isset($_FILES['ImageFile']['name']) )
    {
        $user->image = $_FILES['ImageFile']['name'];
    }

        $errors = $user->isValid();

        if(empty($errors))
        {
            if($user->save())
            {
                echo '<div class="div_1"><div id="div_2">'.
                        '<h1>Thank you</h1><p>'.$user->userName.' you are now registered</p></div></div>';
            }
            else 
            {
                echo '<p class="error"> Oh dear. There was an error</p>';
                echo '<p class = "error">' . mysqli_error($user->dbc) .'</p>';
            }
        }
/***** students to add code here *****/ 

/*********END OF CODE TO BE ADDED*****************/


      }
      else{
        echo '<p class="error"> Error </p>';

        foreach($errors as $msg)
            echo " - $msg<br /> ";
      }
        }




//include the footer html file
include 'Footer.php';
?>
```

My class code:

```
    <?php


//author malcolm.mckenzie

include_once "DBConn.php";

class DO_User extends DBConn {

    private $tableName = 'Users_1';
    //attributes to represent table columns
    public $firstName;
    public $lastName;
    public $email;
    public $userName;
    public $dob;
    public $password;
    public $image;
    //variable to store validation errors
    public $errorMsg;

    //public $dbc=null;

    public function DO_User() {
        $this->getDBConnection();
    }

    public function get($userName) {
        if ($this->getDBConnection()) {

            $q = 'SELECT * FROM Users_1 WHERE UserName=' . $userName;
            $r = mysqli_query($this->dbc, $q);

            if ($r) {
                $row = mysqli_fetch_array($r); 

                $this->userName = $row['UserName'];
                $this->firstName = $row['FName'];
                $this->lastName = $row['LName'];
                $this->email = $row['Email'];
                $this->dob = $row['DOB'];
                $this->password = $row['Password'];
                $this->image = $row['Image'];
                return true;
            }
            else
                $this->displayError($q);
        }
        else
            echo '<p class="error">Could not connect to database</p>';

        return false;
    }

    public function save() {
        if ($this->getDBConnection()) {
            //escape any special characters
            $this->firstName = mysqli_real_escape_string($this->dbc, $this->firstName);
            $this->lastName = mysqli_real_escape_string($this->dbc, $this->lastName);
            $this->userName = mysqli_real_escape_string($this->dbc, $this->userName);
            $this->email = mysqli_real_escape_string($this->dbc, $this->email);
            $this->dob = mysqli_real_escape_string($this->dbc, $this->dob);
            $this->password = mysqli_real_escape_string($this->dbc, $this->password);
            $this->image = mysqli_real_escape_string($this->dbc, $this->image);
            /*if ($this->userName == null) {*/
                $q = "INSERT INTO Users_1 (FName, LName, UserName, DOB, Email, Password, Image) values" .
                        "('" . $this->firstName . "','" . $this->lastName . "','" . $this->userName . "', '". 
                        $this->dob . "','" . $this->email ."','". $this->password . "','". $this->image ."')";
            /*} else {
                $q = "update Users_1 set FName='" . $this->firstName . "', LName='" . $this->lastName .
                        "',Email='" . $this->email . "', Password='" . $this->password . "' where userName = '" . $this->userName . "'";
            }*/


            //   $q = "call SaveUser2($this->userId,'$this->firstName','$this->lastName','$this->email','$this->password')";

            $r = mysqli_query($this->dbc, $q);

            if (!$r) {
                $this->displayError($q);
                return false;
            }

            return true;
        } else {
            echo '<p class="error">Could not connect to database</p>';
            return false;
        }

        return true;
    }

//end of function

    public function delete() {
        if ($this->getDBConnection()) {
            $q = "DELETE FROM Users_1 WHERE userName=" . mysql_escape_string($this->userName);
            $r = mysqli_query($this->dbc, $q);

            if (!$r) {
                $this->displayError($q);
                return false;
            }

            return true;
        } else {
            echo '<p class="error">Could not connect to database</p>';
            return false;
        }
    }

    public function validateFields() {

        return $errors;
    }

    public function isValid() {
        //declare array to hold any errors messages  
        $errors = array();

        if (empty($this->firstName))
            $errors[] = 'You must enter first name';

        if (empty($this->userName))
            $errors[] = 'You must enter last name';
        else {
            if (!$this->validUserName())
                $errors[] = 'This username is already registered';
        }

        if (empty($this->email))
            $errors[] = 'You must enter email';
        else {
            if (!$this->validEmail())
                $errors[] = 'This email address is already registered';
        }

        if (empty($this->password))
            $errors[] = 'You must enter password';

        if (empty($this->image))
            $errors[] = 'You must enter image path';

        return $errors;
    }

    public function validEmail() {
        if ($this->getDBConnection()) {
            $q = "SELECT userName FROM Users_1 WHERE Email='" . mysqli_escape_string($this->dbc, $this->email) . "'";
            $r = mysqli_query($this->dbc, $q);

            if ($r) {
                while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($r)) {
                    $userName = $row[0];

                    //we have found a record that has this email - if it is not the current user the the email
                    //must be registered to someone else
                    if ($userName != $this->userName)
                        return false;
                }
            } else {
                $this->displayError($q);
                return false;
            }
        } else {
            echo '<p class="error">Could not connect to database</p>';
            return false;
        }

        return true;
    }

    public function validUserName() {
        if ($this->getDBConnection()) {
            $q = "SELECT userName FROM Users_1 WHERE userName ='" . mysqli_escape_string($this->dbc, $this->userName) . "'";
            $r = mysqli_query($this->dbc, $q);

            if ($r) {
                while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($r)) {
                    $userName = $row[0];

                    //we have found a record that has this email - if it is not the current user the the email
                    //must be registered to someone else
                    if ($userName != $this->userName)
                        return false;
                }
            } else {
                $this->displayError($q);
                return false;
            }
        } else {
            echo '<p class="error">Could not connect to database</p>';
            return false;
        }

        return true;
    }

    public function getUserFullName() {

        if ($this->getDBConnection()) {

            $q = "SELECT CONCAT(FName, ' ', LName) from Users_1 where UserName = $this->userName";

            $r = mysqli_query($this->dbc, $q);

            if($r){
              $row = mysqli_fetch_array($r);
              return $row[0];
            }
            else {
                $this->displayError($q);
                return false;
            }
        }

        return false;
    }

    private function displayError($q) {
        echo '<p class="error">' . $q . '</p>';
        echo '<p class="error">A database error occurred</p>';
        echo '<p class="error">' . mysqli_error($this->dbc) . '</p>';
    }

}

//end of class decl
?>
```

Comment: What error(s) are you getting?

Comment: What data? The image data? If so, you should consider storing the image to your server as an actual image file rather than storing the data in the database itself. And instead store the image path for each user's profile image.

Comment: Uploaded image file is not even touched.

Answer (score 0):

Try Convert  `<form action="Sign_Up.php" method="post">` to `<form action="Sign_Up.php" method="post"  enctype="multipart/form-data">`

Answer (score 0):

You will have to take care of two things. First if you want to send image image to server, you will have to send it in `multipart/form-data` and second you will have to upload image on server using `move_uploaded_file()`

so make these changes

```
<form action="Sign_Up.php" method="post"  enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

and

```
if( isset($_FILES['ImageFile']['tmp_name']) )
    {   $uploads_dir = '/uploads';
        move_uploaded_file(($_FILES['ImageFile']['tmp_name'], "$uploads_dir/($_FILES['ImageFile']['name']");
        $user->image = $_FILES['ImageFile']['name'];
    }
```

hope it helps :)

Answer (score 0):

You are missing a curly braces `}` at the end of your 'executing code'.

Also, since you are working with files, you will need to provide a `enctype="multipart/form-data"` to your form like this:

```
<form action="Sign_Up.php" method="post"  enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

`$this->image = $row['Image'];` should not be inserted directly to the database since it's a associative array. Instead try `"','". $this->image['name'] ."')";`

If you want to save the image on the server, you will need to move it from the temp directory. After the insert statement, you can add:

```
$uploads_dir = '/upload/path'; //path you want to move the file to
move_uploaded_file($this->image['tmp_name'], $uploads_dir . "/" . $this->image['name']); // move_uploaded_file($from_where, $to_here)
```